# How to add a scrollbar to a drag/drop container with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ng-sortable

[This example](http://a5hik.github.io/ng-sortable/#/kanban) uses the [ng-sortable AngularJS library](https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable) where we can add `n` number of items within a container, and the container expands vertically.  However if I would like to have a fixed-height container, and have the users scroll through each container.

How can this be accomplished with this library or does it require the addition/use of others?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-sortable AngularJS library` plugin creates an ul with `.cards-list` class. You can add below css on the page to get the scrollbar.

```
.card-list {
   max-height: 300px; //set the height based on your requirement
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```